# MySQL function parameter check if NULL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I have a function in MySQL that performs certain calculations. The thing is that the input for one of the parameters can be `NULL` and I need to check, if it's `NULL` or `0` then set the value to `10`. I did the following in the function (`val1` is an input parameter for function and is `int`):

```
IF ((val1 is null) OR (val1=0)) THEN
    SET val1 = 10;
END IF;
```

But, anyways, when I run the function over the table, I get a final value as `NULL`, since at the end the values are multiplied and once multiplied by `NULL` the result is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sql
mysql> DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `check_null_or_zero`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE FUNCTION `check_null_or_zero`(`val1` INT)
    -> RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
    -> RETURN IF(`val1` IS NULL OR `val1` = 0, 10, `val1`);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `check_null_or_zero`(NULL) `null`,
    ->   `check_null_or_zero`(0) `0`,
    ->   `check_null_or_zero`(2) `2`,
    ->   `check_null_or_zero`(10) `10`;
+------+------+------+------+
| null | 0    | 2    | 10   |
+------+------+------+------+
|   10 |   10 |    2 |   10 |
+------+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```